# multiple default controllers in Codeigniter site

Tags: codeigniter

I Have a add multiple default controllers in `Codeigniter` site.

I am unable to do that.

Basically I have to remove controller names from url without `.htaccess` file.

I want to make that dynamic.

I have checked that only default controller name can be removed thats why I want to make dynamic multiple default controllers.

Anyone can help me on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the changes to the **application/config/routes.php** file to do this.

So, if you have a controller called `Secondary` and it had methods like `view, add, search`
you would add:

```
$route['view'] = 'secondary/view';
$route['add'] = 'secondary/add';
$route['search'] = 'secondary/search';
```

NB that if you're passing params to your methods you will need to add entries for these as will, for example if you wanted to pass something to `view()` you would need to:

```
$route['view'] = 'secondary/view';
$route['view/(:any)'] = 'secondary/view/$1';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have multiple controllers like Secondary and Primary etc. How I can user multiple controllers without controller names.

Comment: Then you'll have to right entries for each one. This can not be done dynamically with a standard codeigniter application. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I have seen that in [link](https://gocartdv.com/demo) GOCART demo. But I unable to understand how they did that in GOCART.

Comment: why not a simple lookup function? Have your default controller function check is class/method exists then redirect.